# Solve the second order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a general solution to the equation:
$u''-e^tu'-e^tu=1$.

Comment: How is this nonlinear?

Comment: This is linear.

Comment: Silly me! I was thinking of something else while writing the title!

Comment: Any thoughts about the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{d}{dt} (u \,e^t) = u''-1$$

which is equivalent to

$$u'-e^t u = t+C$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.  This equation has an integrating factor of $e^{-e^t}$, and may be written as

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[ u \,e^{-e^t}\right] = e^{-e^t} (t+C)$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Cheers! I see now.